# How to unload csv file type when unload is compressed with gzip?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Hi I have this query that will Unload data from redshift to S3 that will output as csv file and compressed with gzip. Supposedly, if I extract the gzip it will give me the csv file but instead it extract as "file".

The image attached is the output of partitioned year which is 2018. I was expecting that the unzip file would be on csv format since I specified it in the query but instead it gives me a "file" as file type.
[gzip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk2UF.png)

Query:

```
UNLOAD ($$ SELECT *, (date_part("year", last_updated))::text as year FROM table WHERE date_part("year", last_updated) <= (date_part("year", CURRENT_DATE)-1) $$)
TO 's3://'
IAM_ROLE  ''
PARTITION BY (year) 
CSV DELIMITER AS  '|'
GZIP
PARALLEL FALSE
ALLOWOVERWRITE
MAXFILESIZE AS 100 MB;
```

Comment: Your picture shows a file with a name of `000`. Does your software successfully gunzip the file with that name?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Yes i successfully unzip the GZIP and output the file as seen on the image attached. I was expecting that the unzip file would be on CSV format since I specified it in the query. Thanks

Comment: "CSV" is just a commonly-accepted definition of the format inside the file. What is inside the `000` file? Is it a CSV file delimited by `|`? What is the particular problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I was expecting that the unzip file was going to have a .csv file extension

Comment: No. It will be called `000`, `001`, etc. But it contains the data in the format you requested. Extensions are a Windows concept that isn't always used in Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

A little more on what you are getting would be helpful but I think I see the issue.  You specified a partition column which will split the out output files by this value (multiple files, one per year) but did add the INCLUDE option to partition that will tell UNLOAD to keep the partition values in the output files as well. Since you have only one column, year and this is being used for the partitioned file names you get empty files.

Without more info it will be hard to do better than this interpretation of you commands.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear or lack of information. The image attached was the output of the year 2018 as I partioned it by year. The problem is that I specified the file format as CSV and compressed by GZIP so I'm expecting that when I extract the GZIP it will give me a CSV file instead of "File" as file type. Thanks